# Cassandra query max of a particular column for a particular ID

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to write a Cassandra query and my use case is as follows
Let's say the table is

```
ID  |  Version

1   |    1

1   |    2

2   |    1

2   |    2

2   |    3
```

Now what I want is to get the latest version for all the IDs.

So the query should give me 2 rows. The first with Id:1 Version 2 and second with ID:2 Version:3

I tried a query like `Select * from table where ID=1 and Version= MAX(Version)` but it's not a valid syntax.

Can anybody help in this?

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 1 LIMIT 1` would give you the highest version if your clustering key is Version ordered by descending.

```
CREATE TABLE table (
  id int,
  version int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, version)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (version DESC);
```

Comment: Thanks . also what if I want this result for all the unique template_id? How to modify this query to give me that result?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 1` would give you all results for a template id in order of its version